# How to set limit to open an activity only specific time in a day in android programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I am making game in which i want to set that a user can only play game in a days 3 time..
When he played 3 times in a days then a message will pop up that you have reached to your limit and can not play more..

Comment: use SharedPreferences to save the data

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, explanations are inside code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int lastCheck = 0;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();

    //GET THE LAST CHECKED DATE FROM SHARED PREFERENCES, WE ARE USING DAY OF A MONTH
    lastCheck = pref.getInt("lastcheck", 0);

    //GET THE NUMBER OF TIMES THE ACTIVITY WAS OPENED FROM SHARED PREFERENCES
    int count = pref.getInt("count", 0);

    // IF IT IS A NEW DAY START COUNTING FROM 0 AGAIN
    if(isNewDay()){
        count = 0;
    }        

    // IF COUNT REACHES 5 CLOSE THE ACTIVITY. YOU CAN USE ANY OTHER MEANS TO BLOCK IT. 
    if (count >= 5){
        finish();
    }
    else{
        // ELSE INCREMENT COUNT AND SAVE IT IN THE SHARED PREFERENCES
        count++;
        editor.putInt("count", count);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

// GET THE CURRENT DAY IN THE MONTH AND COMPARE IT WITH THE LAST CHECKED
public boolean isNewDay() {
    Date date = new Date();
    int today = Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("dd",   date).toString());
    boolean ret = lastCheck == 0 || today > lastCheck;
    lastCheck = today;
    return ret;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  private fun isNewDay(): Boolean {
    val date = Date()
    val today: Int = DateFormat.format("dd", date).toString().toInt()
    val ret = lastCheck == 0 || today > lastCheck
    lastCheck = today
    sharedPreferenceHandler.setAlbumCreatedDate(lastCheck)
    return ret

}

if(isNewDay()){
                //do what you want
            }
```